# Webpack Config Error

Tags: webpack

at the basic level,
trying configure webpack with HTML-plugin, getting 2 issues.

1. Why its important to mention entry point and output, that already mention in webpack.config.js
2. html-web-plugin is not generating html.

**package.js**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },

"scripts": {"st": "webpack-dev-server --entry ./src/js/app.js --output-filename ./dist/bundle.js --watch"}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.export = {
  entry: "./src/js/app.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      filename: './dist/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

** 3. how to enable livereload **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two thing, **`webpack`**, which will output files and write them to disk, and **`webpack-dev-server`** which will create a server serving files but without writing them to disk.

Try replacing (in your script `st`) `webpack-dev-server` by `webpack` and remove the entry and output arguments in your command-line. Your file should then be written to disk.

To answer your 3rd question about live-reload, and if you want to use `webpack-dev-server` (that you already installed), take a look at [how to use it](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server).

Comment: as per your suggestion, I did and get the error **throw new Error("'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename");** and this is already in web.config.js